# MySQL - Orders With Maximum Quantity Above Average

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I am trying to solve the below Leetcode MySQL question.

You are running an ecommerce site that is looking for **imbalanced orders**. An imbalanced order is one **whose maximum quantity is strictly greater than the average quantity of every order (including itself)**.

**The average quantity of an order is calculated as (total quantity of all products in the order) / (number of different products in the order). The maximum quantity of an order is the highest quantity of any single product in the order.**

**Write an SQL query to find the order_id of all imbalanced orders.**

Return the result table in any order.

Here's the link to the question and data: https://leetcode.com/problems/orders-with-maximum-quantity-above-average/

Here's a snapshot of the data:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx6h1.png)

Here's my code:

```
WITH average AS (
    SELECT d.order_id, d.product_id, SUM(d.quantity) / COUNT(DISTINCT d.product_id) as average_quantity
    FROM OrdersDetails as d
    GROUP BY d.order_id
    )
SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id
FROM OrdersDetails as o
JOIN average ON
average.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
HAVING MAX(o.quantity) > (SELECT MAX(average_quantity) FROM average)
ORDER BY o.order_id ASC;
```

Edit: I am now getting the correct result - thanks @Gordon Linoff for the suggestion.

Comment: Your CTE is not even valid SQL; it should be throwing an error for mixing aggregation functions and non-aggregated columns in a `SELECT` with no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I am now getting the correct result - thanks @GordonLinoff for the suggestion